# variable name with a white space

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I want to have a variable name with a white space.
Am passing this collection to a gridview and i need the title to have a white space instead of an underscore

```
var registrationReport = (from r in BankMedEntity.Customers
                      select new {r.Id,Customer Type =  r.CustomerType_Id });
```

Any idea on how i can accomplish that?

I need to have the title as "Customer Type" instead of "CustomerType_Id"

Comment: why not handle it in the grid view ?

Comment: I think you're confusing your business logic with your user interface logic. The way you name your variables in your code should not affect how you present the data to your users

Comment: C# can't have white space in variable names.  You'll need to make a custom header in your grid instead of just relying on the default functionality.

Comment: Accept some answers - they can't all have been bad :]

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  I came across this looking for a way to do this, after all you can use `@` to use keywords for property names.  It would be nice for instance for deserializing JSON data from a third party with properties that contain whitespace without using a Dictionary.  Oh well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn this to false

```
AutoGenerateColumns="True"
```

And add your own Bound columns to the Gridview. You will be able to give the columns whatever names you want

Answer (score 5):

You cannot, c# does not allow spaces in variable names. They would be considered different words and the compiler will go "Ahh...What do you mean?"

Comment: so lets say i have a space in the database field , can't i retrieve that ? Sql does allow space in the field name right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is impossible; the compiler has no way of figuring out that the two separate words are actually part of the same variable name.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's unfortunate!  :P

Answer (score 0):

No space is allowed in variable name.
If you want the title of the gridview with no underscore, you should edit the girdview definition in .aspx file.

Comment: the gridview has AutoGenerateColumns="True" so i cant do that