# Export to Excel - How to dynamically set header text using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, export-to-excel

My below code is working well except for one slight issue. When I open the excel sheet, the column headers are pulling directly from the code below I.E.`data.FleetNumber` displays as FleetNumber for the column header.
Is it possible to overwrite this? E.G I want it to display `Fleet No.`

I've done a lot of searching but I cant find an answer. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public void ExportToBeDoneVehiclesToExcel()
    {
        int count = 10;

        var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        var list = vehicleBusinessLogic.GetToBeDoneVehicles(count);
        grid.DataSource = from data in list
                            select new
                            {
                                data.RegistrationID,
                                data.FleetNumber,
                                data.VIN,
                                data.LocationDescription,
                                data.ServiceDescription,
                                data.NextInspectionDueDate
                            };
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Exported_ToBeDoneVehicles.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: What type is `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't test this but it seems logical to me

try specifying the variables names in the list

```
grid.DataSource = from data in list
                        select new
                        {
                            Reg = data.RegistrationID,
                            FleetNumber = data.FleetNumber,
                            VIN = data.VIN,
                            LocationDescription = data.LocationDescription,
                            ServiceDescription = data.ServiceDescription,
                            NextInspectionDueDate = data.NextInspectionDueDate
                        };
```

Comment: Yes that does work for displaying as `Reg` but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Your suggestion does not work if I want to have spaces E.G `Fleet No.` Sorry I should have given `FleetNumber` as the example originally. I have edited my question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Check comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471267/variable-name-with-a-white-space) is this what you looking for .. if yes then [check this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696165/creating-a-gridview-with-columns-generated-at-runtime)